# How to use ARRAY & a DO loop with mulpile variables

Tags: arrays, sas, ssas

I am trying to catergorize the observations that have a specific diagnosis in a specified range & create a new variable. In doing so, I want to set an indicator that will increment if the ID# has more than 1 value in that range. For example, I have 10 patients with 5 different diagnoses but I want to check if they only have it in a specified range between 7-9 & another if it equals say 4. My data looks something like this

````
input id r1-r5;
datalines;
1 8 4 5 6 3
2 4 8 7 2 1
3 1 3 5 9 4
4 2 3 3 6 5
;```

I want the new data table to look like this

`data 2;
input id r1-r5 newvar1 newvar2;
datalines;
1 8 4 5 6 3 1 1
2 4 8 7 2 1 2 1
3 1 3 5 9 4 1 0
4 2 3 3 6 5 0 0
etc..`

After I ran my code, it doubles the observations & duplicates the IDs. SO if I had 30 observations, I would now have 60. Id have 2 ID1, 2 ID2, 2 ID3, etc.

`
DATA want
  set have;
  array r (5) rx1-rx5 ;
  do i= 1 to 5;
  if 6<rx(i)<10 then do;
  var1+1;

end;
end;
output;
var1=0;
do i= 1 to 10;
  if rx(i)=4 then do;
  var2+1;

end;
end;
output;
var2=0;
run;
`

Thanks!
````

Answer (score 0):

The answer is almost the same as in your previous question. You just need another if statement:

```
DATA want;
    set have;
        array rx r1-r5 ;
        newvar1=0 ;
        newvar2=0;
        do i= 1 to 5;
            if 6<rx(i)<10 then do;
                newvar1+1;
            end;
            if rx(i) = 4 then do;
                newvar2+1;
            end;
        end;
        drop i;
run;
```